# Xfce - Xfwm4 - how to edit settings for window shadow?

Tags: xfce, window-manager, xfwm4

Xfwm4 has some gray shadows I guess, but I would like to increase their visibility so that window margins are more clear on dark background. I use a dark GTK theme, and especially on dark background the window margins are not clear.

That's how they look now. On white background:

[image]

On dark background:

[image]

I see some options in Xfconf settings. But how to use those?

[image]

Ideally I would like to change the shadow color to something more striking (blue-gray?). If not, to adjust transparency or thickness, so that the margins are more visible on a dark background. (On light background the contrast is provided by the dark body of the window because I use a dark theme.)

---

This is 18.04, initially Plasma/Kubuntu, but now XFCE 4.12. But even answers on newer versions are welcome (for future use).

```
xfce4-about --version
xfce4-about 4.13.4 (Xfce 4.12)
```

Comment: @guiverc - Did now. I am happy with 4.12. Would like to stay on that.

Comment: Thanks, most of 18.04 is 4.13 (eg. type `xfce4-about --version`), but a few parts remained 4.12.x (eg. `xfce4-panel --version`) thus your release info is important (Xubuntu's release notes refer to 4.12.2; 4.12 was 16.04 which is now EOL for flavors except *Kylin*).  The *was kubuntu* doesn't matter, but thanks.  *yeah 4.14 is all GTK3 which is 19.10*

Comment: @guiverc - I guess the port to gtk3 it's 4.14

Comment: Maybe helpful - https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/start  (if you want to use commands to view/change detail https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query)